# Access elements of a list inside an unordered map in C++

Tags: c++, list, set, unordered-map

My essential doubt is simply this: Suppose I have a map like this

```
std::map<int,std::list<int>> my_map;
```

And now I want to copy each int of the list inside the map into a set of ints. This is the master piece to a solution that I am doing and it misses this part only... I just want to know how to make this process of a list inside a map to a set.

Comment: Yes and? Did you want to ask something?

Comment: I am asking in the comment that is made on the code

Comment: You just state to _want something_, but don't tell about the particular problems you have. Down-/close vote stays ...

Comment: My essential doubt is simply this: Suppose I have a map like this std::map<int,std::list<int>> my_map; And now I want to copy each int of the list inside the map to a set of ints. (for example)... This is the master piece to a solution that I am doing and it misses this part only... I just want to know how to make this process of a list to a set.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you appear to be copying... instead of loop inserting, try using:

```
void insert (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

So for you that becomes (no for loop needed):

```
visitados.insert(graph.begin(), graph.end());
```

I think you're just asking how do you get the data out of that the new map? In an unordered_map you have the syntax correct, you may use the [] operator, but unless you need to squeeze that extra bit of performance out you should stick with std::map. Especially given your difficulties with the STL so far.

Also, I would like to stress using functions such as sort (on a regular map), find, and iterators to make things safer and easier.

[Read more here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator%5B%5D/).

Comment: Many thanks. My essential doubt is simply this: Suppose I have a map like this std::map<int,std::list<int>> my_map;
And now I want to copy each int of the list inside the map to a set of ints. (for example)... This is the master piece to a solution that I am doing and it misses this part only... I just want to know how to make this process of a list to a set.

Comment: Using an iterator to loop, to access just the integer you use: int value = (*itr).first; Is that what you're asking?